# Is there a more explicit way of seeing these code

Tags: vb.net

I got this code from cryptopia C# API sample. I translated that to vb.net. The code is a bit opague. I have no idea what's going on behind the screen.

I added some code that I think would make it more explicit. But they produce different results.

```
    Dim requestUri As String = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Api/GetBalance"
    Dim postData = New With { _
        Key .Currency = "DOT" _
    }

    ' Create Request
    Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage()
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Post
    request.RequestUri = New Uri(requestUri)
    request.Content = New ObjectContent(GetType(Object), postData, New JsonMediaTypeFormatter()) 'I still don't get what the hell is this

    Dim somebyte0 = Await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
    Dim somebyte1 = exchanges.getBytes(request.Content.ToString)

    Dim somestring = exchanges.getString(somebyte0) '
    Dim sometring2 = exchanges.getString(somebyte1) '
```

First the program create an anonymous class type called postData

And then it created a new httprequestmessage. And assign some value to it's content.

I have no idea that a httprequestmessage need content. I know they have URI. I know they have headers. I know they post message. What the hell is "content"

In http request, we usually have texts right. The headers, the uri, the host, the post message, are all texts or strings right.

It seems that the content is some sort of string. Perhaps a json string that encode postData.

I want to see those strings.

The code that I downloaded uses

```
Dim somebyte0 = Await request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
```

Well I am not very familiar with Await. I do not need any asynchrousity. So I want to replace that with something synchronous.

I did

```
Dim somebyte1 = exchanges.getBytes(request.Content.ToString)
```

Where getbytes is defined as

```
Public Shared Function getBytes(secret As String) As Byte()
    Dim result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret) '
    Return result
End Function
```

This is the standard function I used to compute cryptosignature and I have successfully used those for yobit and hitbtc API.

I got different bytes
I turn them back into texts

```
    Dim somestring = exchanges.getString(somebyte0) '7b2243757272656e6379223a22444f54227d
    Dim sometring2 = exchanges.getString(somebyte1) '53797374656d2e4e65742e487474702e4f626a656374436f6e74656e74
```

and I got
7b2243757272656e6379223a22444f54227d

I wonder what's really going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `53797374656d2e4e65742e487474702e4f626a656374436f6e74656e74` to string and you get "System.Net.Http.ObjectContent". This is because you're calling `ToString()` on `request.Content` (which is a System.Net.Http.ObjectContent object). Convert `7b2243757272656e6379223a22444f54227d` and you get "{"Currency":"DOT"}". This is because here you serializing the http content to a byte array (via the `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` call).  The `ObjectContent` class does not have any synchronous methods nor does it have any properties (apart from `Headers`). So I'm afraid you're stuck with using async here.

Comment: How did you convert 53797374656d2e4e65742e487474702e4f626a656374436f6e74656e74  to string

Comment: I've used [http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx](http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx)